# how to insert data as a field in word document from access?

Tags: ms-access, ms-word

I would like insert this in my word document :

> They are xxx person accessing this
>   month on my application.

xxx coming from my access database. I try to add a label, a text box, etc... ubt I can't align the text.

Which is the better solution ?

Thanks a  lot.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered mailmerge and a query?

Comment: I use a query that return a value, but which component could I use to set the value ? And I want to update the value depending of the result of the query.

Comment: Uh, do you know how to do a Word mail merge based on an Access query?